# Losing touch events when updating Views

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, touch

(Apologies for the length, I'm trying to fully describe things...)

My Android app simultaneously displays a number of Views. The Views involve matrix rotation of images and other computationally intensive tasks, so they are created and managed by a separate thread to reduce the workload on the UI thread. When an updated View is ready, it is transferred to the UI thread and the UI thread does a removeViewAt() and addView() to update the screen display, thus making sure that only the UI thread touches the actual user interface. This approach also completely abstracts the UI thread and code from the specifics of the Views being displayed... they are just "objects" to be shown on the screen, each can be updated independently of the others, and so forth. This all works fine, CPU loading is low, etc.

The challenge comes with handling touch events. An active View is associated with its appropriate onTouchListener(), which works fine. When that View is to be updated, its replacement is composed and also associated with the same onTouchListener(). The remove/add process swaps them out and everything works great, except....

If the current View was "in the middle" of a touch event (ACTION_DOWN has occurred) when it is replaced by the new View, neither View will ever receive the associated ACTION_UP. The shared onTouchListener() does receive an ACTION_CANCELLED when the old View is removed, but that's it. The old View isn't alive to "see" the finger release, and the new View wasn't alive when the touch started so it doesn't react to the release either.

This has some interesting results. For one thing, "long clicks" become impossible if the update rate is faster than the long click timeout. You cannot use the onClick... methods for the same reason, because those take action upon RELEASE and you may never see a release. It is possible to take action on the initial touch (instead of the release) but no higher-order touch operations can be performed.

I've considered overlaying the Views with identically sized transparent Views, letting the long-lived overlays capture the touch events while the short-lived Views under them change appearance. But this means any widgets on the underlying Views (Buttons, etc.) cannot handle their own touch events... I will have to write fresh code to recreate all of that functionality.

Another approach is to make the UI code far more complex by eliminating the abstraction between it and the View code. Instead of letting the UI code treat the Views as opaque objects, it would have to "know" their internal details and be able to intelligently manage the individual components that make up the Views. Essentially, the functionality of View composition would be divided across the thread contexts. I anxiously don't want to give up the abstraction of the UI code because it's a very clean architecture that makes maintenance much easier. But it doesn't matter how great it is if it doesn't do the job!

So... any obvious answers here? Anyone else run into the case where changing Views causes touch events to be lost/broken? How did you solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to update content rather than replacing the view? Or would that alter the code too much? Otherwise you could just place all of your views that are causing the trouble inside of a ViewGroup for each one. The Views themselves get changed out but not the ViewGroup. The ViewGroup would be the one receiving the touch events instead. The downside here is that you end up with a whole lot more views on the screen and objects in memory. I hope those suggestions are helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Updating content is what I meant by losing the abstraction between the UI and View code. It means the UI has to know a lot more about the Views it is displaying. I'd like to keep that abstraction if possible. As for using a ViewGroup to contain them, that doesn't change the situation because you connect the child *View* to an onTouch...() method, not its parent container. Going with a parent container would be the same as overlaying with a transparent View - the touch events go to a different object and you'd have to coordinate between the Views or ViewGroups.

Comment: Actually the ViewGroup solution would work, because these can receive MotionEvents as well, being descendants of View. As long as it has an onTouch method as well, and your views just return true in their onTouch method (or have no onTouch method), MotionEvents will get passed up the view hierarchy allowing for the ViewGroup to receive all of the desired events then take action perhaps calling a method in the child view.

Comment: Oh, I agree it could be *made* to work. But as I said, the VG would get "raw" events that your own code woudl have to correlate via its X/Y coordinates to the target child View. That's the same as would happen with a transparent overlaid View at the top of the Z order, which is another approach that could be *made* to work. It's just not elegant.

Comment: Yes, but what if each of the views was wrapped in its own VG that was defined as wrap_content to fit the form of the view it wraps. Not just one VG but one VG for each View. If that isn't an elegant enough solution, I'm sorry. I tried to search for a way to transfer a MotionEvent to another View, but I don't see a way to do so. I hope you find a solution that fits your purpose well, and I hope that I have contribute some ideas that you might find helpful.

Comment: OK, that would at least segregate the events to the View in question. Definitely an improvement to the overlaid transparent View. I am now working on a different approach: Having the UI thread call a callback-like method in the class controlling the View, thus letting the UI thread execute the View updating code. What this does is allow the View to be updated (as you suggested) instead of entirely replaced, while maintaining the abstraction between the modules. The UI module never needs to know the intimate details about the View - it just blindly calls a method on demand.

Comment: (continued) Each View would thus have something like a "serviceView()" method. Changes are composed by another thread (still keeping the heavy lifting off of the UI thread) and then that other thread notifies the UI thread to call serviceView(). serviceView() is part View's class so it has access to the class's internals, even though it's being *executed* by the UI thread. Thus the details of the View are isolated from the UI's own code, but the UI thread is doing the updating of the live, onscreen View. And since the View is being changed rather than replaced, the touch system is unaffected.

Comment: More: I have prototyped this and it's working well. Best of both worlds. Hope it helps someone else someday! Thanks for the back and forth, it helped me consider the options.